# Рекурсия, вывод значения функции

Tags: python, рекурсия

Есть такая вот рекуррентная функция:

```
def Re (n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n*Re(n-1)+1/n
Re(3)
```

Я хочу, что на экран выводилось каждое значение `n*Re(n-1)+1/n`, но не знаю как это сделать.

Если сделать так:

```
print(n*Re(n-1)+1/n)
```

То вылетает ошибка:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return` оставляете, на экран печатаете промежуточный результат.

```
def re(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        res = n*re(n-1)+1/n
        print(res)
        return res
```